# Terraform resource with for_each depending on a boolean variable

Tags: terraform

Given the following map and its implementation:

```
variable "tunnel_service_maps" {
  default = {}
  type = map(object({
    target_service          = string
    create_service_token    = bool
  }))

tunnel_service_maps = {
  tunnel1 = {
    target_service          = "http://tunnel1"
    create_service_token    = true
  }
  tunnel2 = {
    target_service          = "http://tunnel2"
    create_service_token    = false
  }
  tunnel3 = {
    target_service          = "http://tunnel3"
    create_service_token    = true
  }
}
```

I want to create the following resource exclusively if `create_service_token == true`:

```
resource "example_resource" "example" {
  for_each       = var.tunnel_service_maps # <- row to change
  name           = "allow-service-token-${each.value.target_service}"
}
```

The expected results will be 2 example resources created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be easy to achieve:

```
resource "example_resource" "example" {
  for_each       = { for k, v in var.tunnel_service_maps : k => v if v.create_service_token }
  name           = "allow-service-token-${each.value.target_service}"
}
```

Comment: Seems not happy about create_service_token. 
`This object does not have an attribute named "create_service_token".`

Comment: I did a test with local variables so that should work, based on the input you provided in your question.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I confirmed it's working. Many thanks